# Channel foci and nondeity Clerics- Who are your faithful?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Channel Foci](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/toys-games-puzzles#table-channel-foci) allow a cleric to "charge" items with holy power in order to gain item-specific powers. For example, a shield can be filled with holy power to gain extra AC.

Some of these items can be passed to others, and only work for members of the same faith. (Hallowed chalice, Instrument of the divine, teaching staff...)

If you are a cleric of a concept, rather than a deity, who are the members of your faith for the purposes of sharing these benefits?

Comment: This is why choosing faiths isn't just for clerics, and how players who don't bother to choose a faith for their PC lose out. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules don't say; it's left up to the DM.

That said, I basically see three options that a DM could go with.

## The faith of a cleric of a concept is personal

There simply isn't anyone who shares your faith, and you cannot take advantage of the option to share these items. Small drawback, arguably, for the freedom to pick your own domains.

## All clerics of a concept of the same alignment share a faith

This is simple, but it's extremely broad, far broader than for clerics of a deity, which doesn't seem right.

## Clerics of a concept share a faith of the concepts are sufficiently similar

This is probably the best answer, but offers the least predictive value. As DM, I would probably base it at least in part on domains: shared domains would mean pretty strong likelihood that the faith is similar enough.

Comment: I replaced some words that I _think_ were put there by an autocorrect. Could you check my edit?

Comment: @doppelgreener Hah, usually I’m quite vigilant about going through my phone’s submissions, but not today, apparently! Thank you very much, those were some silly autocorrects.

Comment: They were ;) you're welcome